# C# Selenium printing div content not working properly

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, console

I'm using C# Console Application with Selenium and trying to print the content from a div-tag, but for some reason the only output i get is "OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Firefoxwebelement". What can be the cause?

```
Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='footer']")));
```

Comment: You've got the element - you need to print its contents.

Comment: No matter how i do it, the output is always "OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Firefoxwebelement". Could it be anything wrong with the last update?

Comment: No - the output is fine - you need to access the value of the element. Try OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Firefoxwebelement.InnerHtml or look up the documentation for how to get the value/contents of the element. You have the element and it's supposed to return the element, so everything is working fine - you just need to find out how to access the element's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='footer']")).Text);
```